# Powershell v4: Sending added types to remote Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, remote-server, powershell-4.0

I have a file Models.cs with regular C# classes in it, on my main script I Add-Type it, but I also need those same models on scripts I run on remote machines with Invoke-Command.

```
 $Server = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ip`
    -ConfigurationName ConfigurationExmpl`
    -Credential $credential -filepath "path/to/script.ps1"
```

I know I could just do

```
 Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"   
            public class ServerModel
            {
                 public string Name;
                 public string Hostname;
                 public string Ip;
                 public string OperatingSystem;
            }"
```

in the script I'm sending to the remote, but then I would have the same models defined in multiple places and I want to have them all in Models.cs

Is it possible to pass the Models.cs file together with the script to be executed and then try to read from the same dir, or some other ways to do this?

Comment: Why not include the `Add-Type` call in `script.ps1` in the first place, if it depends on it?

Comment: But isn't it going to be executed in a different location than the script is stored at?

Comment: If I do Add-Type in script.ps1 it tries to look for Models.cs in the remote machine, because that's where it is executed

Answer (score 0):

to expand on what Mathias commented; if you're able to call the script over UNC path, place the Models.cs in the same folder and have the script also call it (over UNC path as well to be safe)

Comment: I am sending that script from my local machine to the remote machine and executing it there. The script is not stored on the remote.